# MySQL Select Row from table WHERE value > 0

Tags: php, mysql

Hey im having trouble constructing this mysql query its stumped me for about a week now im hoping someone has the answer and can help me learn!

my table looks like this:
[image: my table looks like this]

**What I want**
Im looking to get all of the values out of my table WHERE the username OR email = 'abc123' AND WHERE the values of attack strength defense agility etc... are > 0

So basically how could I only get rows where the values in my columns are greater than 0 and the values are associated with the correct username and email

any help would be much appreciated! im not sure if i explained this the best way but id love to help clarify!

here's what i was working with so far

```
SELECT Attack, Strength, Defense, Magic, Ranged, Prayer, Runecrafting, Dungeoneering, Construction, Constitution, Agility, Herblore, Thieving, Crafting, Slayer, Hunter, Mining, Smithing, Fishing, Cooking, Firemaking, Woodcutting, Farming, Summoning FROM experience WHERE email =  abc123 OR username = abc123
```

Comment: And why doesn't this work?  `where (email =  'abc123' OR username = 'abc123') and attack > 0 and strength > 0 and . . . `

Comment: @GordonLinoff your the SQL god. is there any indexing issues with LFlares answer below?

Comment: @Dagon . . . An index can't be used for the summation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks, just another thought .. as soon as the db finds attack is not greater than 0 its going to move to next row to check right? it wouldent bother checking all the conditions first? sorry totally off topic ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to get the data out of the database to way I wanted it so I decided it would be better to simply pull out all the data from the table and filter it using php

```
$stmt2 = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM experience WHERE username = :uname OR email = :email");
$stmt2->execute(array(':uname' => $_SESSION['username'], ':email' => $_SESSION['email']));
$rowExperience = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$skills = array("Attack", "Strength", "Defense", "Magic", "Ranged", "Prayer", "Runecrafting", "Dungeoneering", "Construction",
                 "Constitution", "Agility", "Herblore", "Thieving", "Crafting", "Fletching", "Slayer", "Hunter", "Mining", "Smithing","Fishing", "Cooking", "Firemaking", "Woodcutting", "Farming", "Summoning");


           for($i = 0; $i < count($skills); $i++) {
                if(intval($rowExperience[$skills[$i]]) > 0) {
                    echo '<td style="color:grey;">' . $skills[$i] . ' - ' . $rowExperience[$skills[$i]] . '</td>';   
                }           

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Attack, Strength, Defense, Magic, Ranged, Prayer, Runecrafting, Dungeoneering, Construction, Constitution, Agility, Herblore, Thieving, Crafting, Slayer, Hunter, Mining, Smithing, Fishing, Cooking, Firemaking, Woodcutting, Farming, Summoning FROM experience WHERE (email =  "abc123" OR username = "abc123") AND Attack > 0 AND Strength > 0 AND Defense > 0 AND *etc*
```

Comment: this wont work because if any 1 column is greater than 0 then its going to select every row even if that particular row is 0 i just ran the query and tested it! :(

Comment: Change the ORs in the final group to ANDs, then it will only return rows where every attribute is greater than zero (edited to demonstrate)

Comment: when I ran the query with AND's it returned an empty result set, most likely because every single value MUST be greater than 0 for it to return ANY values otherwise it returns no values apparently thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

And why doesn't this work? `where (email = 'abc123' OR username = 'abc123') and attack > 0 and strength > 0 and` . . .

It works like the following if:
`if( (email == 'abc123' || username == 'abc123') && stength > 0)`

The first parts between "()" with "||" means that at last one the conditions inside of it must be true. And && outside means that also the last condition must be true.

I also recommend you to use user ID because it's really better than user name/email

Comment: when I ran the query with AND's it returned an empty result set, most likely because every single value MUST be greater than 0 for it to return ANY values otherwise it returns no values apparently thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

## Your solution

```
SELECT Attack, Strength, Defense, Magic, Ranged, Prayer, Runecrafting, Dungeoneering, Construction, Constitution, Agility, Herblore, Thieving, Crafting, Slayer, Hunter, Mining, Smithing, Fishing, Cooking, Firemaking, Woodcutting, Farming, Summoning FROM experience WHERE (email = abc123 OR username = abc123) AND (Attack + Strength + Defense + Magic + Ranged + Prayer + Runecrafting + Dungeoneering + Construction + Constitution + Agility + Herblore + Thieving + Crafting + Slayer + Hunter + Mining + Smithing + Fishing + Cooking + Firemaking + Woodcutting + Farming + Summoning > 0);
```

Unfortunately, unless you have a column to sum up all the statistics, the only way to achieve you want is to manually compare all, in which case I use `+` to sum it up.